# Javascript learning classes questions

Tags: javascript, class, object

I've been working with javascript for a while but never made any classes and my work has been getting messy with tons of unorganized functions. So now I am learning how to use classes, and I have question.

How can I execute functions within a class, example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function (){
            var object = new testClass("test123");
            alert(object.content);
        }
        function testClass (id){
            this.object = document.getElementById(id);
            this.content = this.getContent(); //<- this is what I want to do
            this.getContent = function (){
                return this.object.innerHTML;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test123">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically how can i call upon function inside of the class inside of the class? In the example how can I get `this.getContent` to return `"Hello World"`.

I know I can do it like :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function (){
            var object = new testClass("test123");
            alert(object.getContent());
        }
        function testClass (id){
            this.object = document.getElementById(id);
            this.getContent = function (){
                return this.object.innerHTML;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test123">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using chrome to test. I am doing this wrong, can it be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `getContent` before creating it.
Move the function call below the assignment.